# User defined function with XMLSERIALIZE

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, user-defined-functions

I am writing a user defined function in pl/sql for an Oracle database. The function purpose is converting an xml field to a clob. This is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IDS_ORA.castField_xml_to_clob (xmlField IN XMLTYPE)
  RETURN CLOB
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN XMLSERIALIZE(CONTENT xmlField AS CLOB NO INDENT)
END;
/
```

Compiling fails with this error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "XMLFIELD" when expecting one of the
>   following: . (    ) , * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not
>   rem =>     <> o != o ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
>   like4 likec as between from using || multiset member    submultiset
>   Function:IDS_ORA.CASTFIELD_XML_TO_NVARCHAR(IDS_ORA@172.25.1.134:1522:sviluppo)
>   5 31

It seems a generic error to me, so I tried using `XMLSERIALIZE` directly inside a query and it works.

```
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(CONTENT "AttributesValue" AS CLOB no INDENT)
FROM IDS_ORA."Job";
```

This means the syntax is correct, what is it complaining about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLSerialize isn't a native PL/SQL function. [Many SQL functions can be called directly in PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-828EB30D-32B4-49E3-90D5-9302172D6EC2), such as `to_date()`; unfortunately this isn't one of them. (I don't think any of the XML-related functions can be, in fact).

> In PL/SQL expressions, you can use all SQL functions except:
>   ...
>
> - XML functions (such as `APPENDCHILDXML` and `EXISTSNODE`)

You can't use direct assignment, so you need to use a query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION castField_xml_to_clob (xmlField IN XMLTYPE)
  RETURN CLOB
AS
  result CLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(CONTENT xmlField AS CLOB NO INDENT)
  INTO result
  FROM dual;

  RETURN result;
END;
/

Function CASTFIELD_XML_TO_CLOB compiled
```

Which adds another context switch, so unless you're trying to have a common place to control indent options for all formatted XML so you can change them all in one place, I'm not sure this gains you anything over just calling XMLSerialize directly wherever you were going to call this UDF.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to create this function to specialize a linq query (I have created the same version of this function in SQL Server), so the situation is actually more complicated. I decided to use `XMLSERIALIZE` because I have to remove indenting and line feed from xml. I saw I can use `getclobval()` but I can only remove indenting, and eventually replacing line feed. Are you aware of other ways to do what I want?

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara - using XMLSerialize is fine I think, I was just questioning why you were wrapping it in your own function really. Maybe Linq doesn't understand that function? You could also do `xmlquery('/*' passing xmlField returning content).getclobval()` which should strip both, but using XMLSerialize is maybe more obvious.